# How to know which slave run the job?

Tags: jenkins

My job failed due to some reason. I want to go to the machine who actually run the job.

1. How do I know if a job is configured to use slaves?
2. How do I know which slave was used in that job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default all jobs are able to use all nodes, including the master as an executor. If you want to lock a job down to a particular slave, you can do so by selecting it in `Job > Configuration > General > Restrict where this job can run`.

To see which host a job ran on, click on the build number and in the top right it will say 'Started ~duration~ on ~host~', where ~host~ is your slave (or master).

Comment: ```Started 10 hr ago
Took 4 min 46 sec``` Mine doesn't say where it started. That is all that it says.  :/